# Can't query, run or stop a Windows Service

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-studio-2012, service

I have created my first Windows service following [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx) instruction. I can start or stop my service from the Service panel in Manage-> My computer without problem.
The **service account is "LocalSystem"** so, I think, I'm ok with privileges.
Now I want to communicate with my service from another app, but first of all I want to stop or start my service.

Following this [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686315(v=vs.85).aspx) I Write this code:

```
    SC_HANDLE schSCManager;
    SC_HANDLE schService;
    LPCWSTR szSvcName = _T("MyNewService");

    // Get a handle to the SCM database. 

    schSCManager = OpenSCManager( 
        NULL,                    // local computer
        NULL,                    // ServicesActive database 
        SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);  // full access rights 
    if (NULL == schSCManager) 
    {
        printf("OpenSCManager failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    // Get a handle to the service.
    schService = OpenService( 
        schSCManager,            // SCM database 
        szSvcName,               // name of service 
        SERVICE_CHANGE_CONFIG);  // need change config access 
    if (schService == NULL)
    { 
        printf("OpenService failed (%d)\n", GetLastError()); 
        CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);
        return;
    }   
    //OK until now

    // Check the status in case the service is not stopped. 
    SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS ssStatus; 
    DWORD dwBytesNeeded;

    if (!QueryServiceStatusEx( 
            schService,                     // handle to service 
            SC_STATUS_PROCESS_INFO,         // information level
            (LPBYTE) &ssStatus,             // address of structure
            sizeof(SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS), // size of structure
            &dwBytesNeeded ) )              // size needed if buffer is too small
    {
        //printf("QueryServiceStatusEx failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        CString str;
        str.Format(_T("QueryServiceStatusEx failed (%d)\n"), GetLastError()); //ERROR 5: ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED
        CloseServiceHandle(schService); 
        CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);
        return; 
    }

    // Check if the service is already running. It would be possible 
    // to stop the service here, but for simplicity this example just returns. 

    if(ssStatus.dwCurrentState != SERVICE_STOPPED && ssStatus.dwCurrentState != SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
    {
        printf("Cannot start the service because it is already running\n");
        CloseServiceHandle(schService); 
        CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);
        return; 
    }
```

In any case I get the **error number 5**, that is "*ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED: The handle does not have the SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS access right*", but I'm not sure where is the problem. The service has LocalSystem account option that means all privileges and I'm the admin of my computer.. what's wrong?

I also tried with ControlService trying to start or stop the service but I get the same error about rights

```
BOOL success = ::ControlService(schService, SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP, &ss);
```

I'm on Visual Studio 2013 Update 2.
Thank you

Comment: Should be posted as answer.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: The answer from Mohamad was first posted as comment. He later removed the comment and added the answer, which left my comment hanging. Imagine I also remove my comment, and all that is left is your question :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to be a little bit confused about terms "privileges" and "access rights". You are quite right that the LocalSystem account is really a privileged one, at least for actions on the local computer. However, even a privileged user must know how to take advantage if her privileges (how things work).

When an application wants to work with an object (e.g. a service), it has to declare its intention to the Windows kernel (done via `OpenSCManager` and `OpenService` in your code). The application identifies the object (e.g. by service name) and also informs the kernel what sorts of things it plans to do with it. These "sorts of things" are called "access rights" and the kenrel decides whether the application is privileged enough to obtain the access rights it is requesting. In your code, you are requesting all access rights (`SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS`) for the SC manager and an access right to change configuration of your service (`SERVICE_CHANGE_CONFIG`). Then, you attempt to query status of your service, but you did not declare this intention to the kernel when requesting access to the service (the `OpenService` call). That's why you get the "access denied" error.

Here is a list of access rights defined for services and SC manager(s): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685981(v=vs.85).aspx. The document also contains information about which access rights you need to perform which actions.

To open a service, you need only the `SC_MANAGER_CONNECT` access right to its SC manager. To query service status, the `SERVICE-QUERY_STATUS` access right is required. To stop the service, request the `SERVICE_STOP` right.

So, the short version is: specify `SERVICE_STOP | SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS` desired access mask when calling `OpenService`, and optionally `SC_MANAGER_CONNECT` in the `OpenSCManager` call.

Comment: Thank you, now is clear.. I miss the difference between my code and the example code where, in the `OpenService` function, I put `SERVICE_CHANGE_CONFIG` instead of the correct mask or `SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS`. If I can, I have another question: if from my application, after start the service, I want to send a customize data object with some data, what is the best way avoiding to save files? I read about RPC but can0t find a good tutorial.

Comment: You can use shared memory, named pipes, sockets... There is quite plenty of ways of communication. I think sockets should be the easiest to implement. Keep in mind that the service should verify correctness of the inputs comming unprivileged or less privileged application that can be potentialy malicious.

Comment: Thank you, looking for some tutorial. If you have someone, pls link

Comment: Thanks, man. Was beginning to turn really mad. Your `SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS` made my code work (for some reasons, I was using totally unrelated access rights, here).

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

Your example program does not have the correct privileges to stop/start your service. It does not matter what privileges your service has.

**Solution**

Try running your example program as administrator by right-clicking on the exe file and selecting "Run as administrator".

If you need to elevate your process programmatically then have a look at [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vistacompatteam/2006/09/25/elevate-through-shellexecute/).

Answer (score 0):

```
    UINT GetServiceStatus(LPCTSTR ServiceName)
    {
        SC_HANDLE       schService;
        SC_HANDLE       schSCManager;
        DWORD           ErrorCode;
        SERVICE_STATUS  ssStatus;
        UINT            return_value;

        schSCManager = OpenSCManager(
            NULL,                   // machine (NULL == local)
            NULL,                   // database (NULL == default)
            SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS   // access required
        );

        if (!schSCManager) 
            return -1;

        schService = OpenService(schSCManager, ServiceName, SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS);

        if (!schService) 
        {
            ErrorCode = GetLastError();
            CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);

            if (ErrorCode == ERROR_SERVICE_DOES_NOT_EXIST) 
                return -2;
            else 
            return -1;
        }

        QueryServiceStatus(schService, &ssStatus);

        if (ssStatus.dwCurrentState == SERVICE_RUNNING) 
            return_value = 1;
        else 
            return_value = 0;

        CloseServiceHandle(schService);
        CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);

        return return_value;
    }
```